# PHP: Bootstrap Radio button value not showing

Tags: php, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have a bootstrap form with 3 radio buttons. I am saving the value into a variable so that I can use to save into database and email.

**HTML:**

```
<form class="form-horizontal form-validate" id="signup-form" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="signupForm" />

<div class="control-group">
  <label class="control-label">Seed program</label>
  <div class="controls">
  <input type="radio" name="signup" value="Seed Program" checked="checked"/>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="control-group">
  <label class="control-label">Gift Wrap Program</label>    
  <div class="controls">
  <input type="radio" name="signup" value="Gift Wrap" />
  </div>
</div>

<div class="control-group">
  <label class="control-label">Sign up for both</label> 
  <div class="controls">
  <input type="radio" name="signup" value="Both" />
  </div>
</div>

<input type="submit" class="btn btn-large btn-block btn-success" value="Submit" name="submit">
</form>
```

**PHP:**

```
if(isset($_POST['signupForm'])){

  if(isset($_POST['signup'])) {
    $signup = $_POST["signup"];
  }
  else{
    $signup = "Nothing was selected";
  }

}
```

**The Problem:**

The Problem is that I can only get the value of the first radio button which has the "checked" attribute. If I select any of the other two, I wont get anything and the value shows empty.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: Have you tried doing a `var_dump($_POST)` to see everything that's coming through?

Comment: Yeh. I get  ["signup"]=> string(0) which means no string when I do a var_dump($_POST)

Answer (score 0):

try using

```
 <input type="radio" name="signup" value="Seed Program" checked />
```

and not

```
 <input type="radio" name="signup" value="Seed Program" checked="checked"/>
```